# How can I create block (multiline) comments in Lisp code?

Tags: elisp, comment

How can I do multiline / block comments in Lisp code - e.g. in the `init.el`.

In Python I would do it like this

```
"""Block
comment
"""
```

In C/C++ like this

```
/*
Block
comment
*/
```

The use case is to out-comment some code blocks for debugging and error diagnosis.

Comment: Emacs Lisp has no multi-line comments, but [Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6365334/850781) does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emacs Lisp doesn't have multiline comments. Neither does Python, for that matter. `"""…"""` in Python delimit a multiline string. Emacs has multiline string literals, but they're delimited simply by `"…"`, so you can't use them to make a block of code inert if that block contains ordinary string literals.

You can just select the block and use `M-;` or `M-x comment-region`. This will comment out all the selected lines.

Assuming what you want to comment out is a syntactically correct block of code with balanced parentheses, you can put `(when nil` before it and `)` after it, or even shorter, `[` before and `]` after. `(when nil …)` doesn't execute any of the code in `…` and evaluates to `nil`. `'(…)` doesn't evaluate any of the code in `…` and evaluates to a list object. `[…]` doesn't evaluate any of the code in `…` and evaluates to a vector object. This doesn't require any change to intermediate lines, and nests. This is similar to using `#if 0` … `#endif` in C or C++, although the requirement on having a syntactically well-formed block is higher since this Emacs Lisp equivalent requires the parentheses in the block to be balanced.

```
[
(some)
(code)
]
```

Comment: `M-;` is it! Great! Is there an opposite of `comment-region`? Can't find one with my way to search the docs.

Comment: @buhtz `uncomment-region` is the opposite of `comment-region`. `M-;` uncomments if the region is fully commented out, so a second `M-;` will undo the previous one.

Comment: And here I was writing out my own `(defmacro greater-comment (&rest _))` like a newb, haha.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax for multi-line comments (AFAIK).  Just select the target code blocks and do `comment-dwim` which will comment/uncomment each line.

Comment: I'd add that `comment-dwim` is bound to `M-;` by default.

Answer (score 1):

First, yes, it's true that Emacs Lisp does not have a real block-comment syntax.  This is different from Common Lisp, which has **`#|`** ... **`|#`**.

That said, you can use `;`-style comments to get much of the effect of `#|`...`|#` commenting, if not quite the same flexibility or appearance.

---

My answer is to use **`comment-region`**, *not* `comment-dwim`.  IMO, the former is much more useful when you want to, for example, nest blocks of comments and, in particular, unnest a given level of nesting. I use `comment-dwim` (`M-;`) only for single-semicolon comments after a line of code.

For `comment-region`:

- A plain `C-u` unnests a full level of comments, for the region.
- A negative prefix arg removes that many comment chars. E.g., `M- - 2` removes two `;` chars.

---

However, I actually prefer the following, **`comment-region-lines`** from library [`misc-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/misc-cmds.el), because I typically want to comment/uncomment full **lines** as a block comment.  I bind it to **`C-x C-;`**.

```lisp
(defun comment-region-lines (beg end &optional arg)
  "Like `comment-region' (which see), but comment or uncomment whole lines."
  (interactive "*r\nP")
  (when (> beg end) (setq beg  (prog1 end (setq end  beg))))
  (let ((bol  (save-excursion (goto-char beg) (line-beginning-position)))
        (eol  (save-excursion (goto-char end) (if (bolp) (point) (line-end-position)))))
    (comment-region bol eol arg)))
```

Here's the doc string of `comment-region`, which the doc of `comment-region-lines` refers to:

> **`comment-region`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `newcomment.el`.
>
> `(comment-region BEG END &optional ARG)`
>
> Comment or uncomment each line in the region.
>
> With just **`C-u`** prefix arg, uncomment each line in region `BEG` .. `END`.
>
> *Numeric* prefix `ARG` means use `ARG` comment characters.
> If `ARG` is negative, delete that many comment characters instead.
>
> The strings used as comment starts are built from `comment-start`
> and `comment-padding`; the strings used as comment ends are built
> from `comment-end` and `comment-padding`.
>
> By default, the `comment-start` markers are inserted at the
> current indentation of the region, and comments are terminated on
> each line (even for syntaxes in which newline does not end the
> comment and blank lines do not get comments).  This can be
> changed with `comment-style`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean commenting for functions/variables docs, then let's look at this example, taken at random:

```
(defun centaur-tabs-current-tabset (&optional update)
  "Return the tab set currently displayed on the tab bar.
If optional argument UPDATE is non-nil, call the user defined function
`centaur-tabs-current-tabset-function' to obtain it.  Otherwise return the
current cached copy."
  (and update centaur-tabs-current-tabset-function
       (setq centaur-tabs-current-tabset
         (funcall centaur-tabs-current-tabset-function)))
  centaur-tabs-current-tabset)
```

It is self-explaining: start with `"` and when finished close also with `"`.

Comment: That is the "documentation string" of the function or variable. It is not a comment as the language defines comments (anything from a semicolon to the end of the line).